# How to write sql query using group by

Tags: sql, database

I have this table:

```
actors(id: int, first_name: string, last_name: string, gender: string)
directors(id: int, first_name: string, last_name: string)
directors genres(director id: int, genre: string, prob: 
float)
movies(id: int, name: string, years: int, rank: 
float,)
movies directors(director id: int, movie id: int)
movies genres(movie id: int, genre: string)
roles(actor id: int, movie id: int, role: string)
```

I want to find the year for each genre in which maximum movies for that genre were made.

I am doing the following but I'm stuck, please help!

```
select m.YEAR, count(m.year) as c, genre 
from movies_genres, 
     movies m 
where m.id = movies_genres.movie_id 
group by genre, m.year;
```

Answer (score 1):

you are getting the count of the movies for each genre for each year which is great. Now you just need to select the max of those by placing your query as a derived table.

```
select genre, year, max(c) mc
from
    (select m.YEAR, count(m.year) as c, genre 
    from movies_genres mg
         inner join movies m
             on m.id = mg.movie_id 
    group by genre, m.year)
group by genre, year
```

Comment: Can you give me more info as to why this isn't working? perhaps Im not understanding your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using SQL Server or Oracle or DB2 this should work.

```
SELECT genre, year, number
FROM 
(
  SELECT genre, year, number,
         row_number() over (PARTITION BY genre ORDER BY number DESC) as rank
  FROM
  (
    SELECT mg.genre, m.year, count(*) as number
    FROM movies_genres mg
    JOIN movies m on m.id = mg.movie_id
    GROUP BY mg.genre, m.year
  ) A
) B
WHERE rank = 1
```

How it works:  From inner to outer, first you get the count for all genres and years.  Then you rank each genre's years by count, finally select the items which are largest.